# Better notification of closed question in process of being answered?

Tags: discussion, answers, closed-questions

I've just been scuppered answering a question on SO, which was closed after I'd started to write an answer for it. Whilst I don't entirely agree with the close reason (a gold badge user marked as duplicate, which admittedly it did look like from the title but the content actually asked a different question), the most frustrating part is that I'd spent a few minutes writing an answer only to be unable to submit it at all.

The "Post your answer" button was greyed when I came to click it, but I hadn't noticed this change until then. Did I miss any other flags / notices (the question title was below the fold at this point)?

Should there be a more obvious alert / pop-up, as if the site isn't going to take my answer, why let someone blindly continue to type it out (unknowingly)? Obviously, any time spent answering a question after it's been closed will always be wasted.

Comment: It's been a while since I've had a question closed from under my feet (and this has happened to me only on Meta) but as I recall, there's a notification that comes up. I don't recall ever missing it.

Comment: I was surprised I didn't see any notification (as I do when new answers are posted etc). I'm interested then in what I should have seen and why I might not have noticed it?

Comment: It also wastes your time that you spent typing out your answer while it was closed. And if you dare post a placement answer just to protect yourself you'll find that closed with 50 downvotes too

Comment: @CashCow Which is why you shouldn't be spending a lot of time trying to answer questions that don't meet the site's guidelines.  Look for questions that meet the site's guidelines to answer.

Comment: @Servy My answer wasn't going to a question that didn't meet the site's guidelines - it was another victim of an overzealous gold badge user.

Comment: @Mikaveli The comment wasn't directed at you, it was directed at the person trying to answer questions that he knows are off topic for the site, and then getting mad when his off topic answers aren't well received by the community.

Answer (score 2):

There is a banner shown at the top of the screen, and it stands out pretty strongly as is.  I don't see a need for anything more:

> [image]

Comment: I didn't get that banner - my only visual clue was the greyed out button. I scrolled back up to the title and did an "Open in new tab" to discover the question had been closed.

Comment: Is it displayed on page refresh after the close or using AJAX etc?

Comment: @Mikaveli The banner is displayed via websockets. Do you see any of the banners about new questions or edits on the question happening? Maybe give the http://websocketstest.com/ a whirl if not?

Comment: According to that site, only websockets on port 443 work for me.

Comment: That isn't a notification that the question is about to be closed, it is a notification that it is closed. A 5 minutes warning would be nice. Even a 30 second warning

Comment: @CashCow You never know when a question is 30 seconds, or 5 minutes, away from being closed.  Such a message wouldn't be possible.

Comment: I just duplicated my tab in chrome, my answer was there, the button was no longer disabled and I clicked it and submitted..

Comment: Actually I shouldn't tell you lot that. Yes there is supposed to be a grace period. So let's have the button remain enabled.

Comment: @CashCow We don't *want* people answering closed questions.  The whole point of closing questions is to prevent answers.

Comment: yeah and you don't want people typing long answers

Comment: anyway a gold badger can close a question temporarily to stop others sneaking an answer in, then type out a really good answer, cancel the close then post the answer..

Comment: @CashCow That would be abusive behavior that you could report.  I've yet to see it happen, because it's just so easy to catch people doing it and it leaves a permanent record of the activity.

Comment: Yes it clearly would be. I've never tried it myself. I'd be interested to know how you'd easily catch it though.

Comment: @CashCow You'd see the question closed as a duplicate of a post that it's not at all a duplicate of.  That kinda stands out.  It only takes *one* person to notice it and flag for it.