# Questions being closed as answers are being written

Tags: feature-request, answers, closed-questions

Three times this week I've attempted to write answers for people and, just before I click 'Post Answer', a notification appears warning me that the question was closed and no new answers will be accepted.

Obviously, this is an absolute pain in the derrière, as like anybody here, I hate my time being wasted. The last time it happened (5 minutes ago), I only wasted about 7-8 minutes. However, the time before this was much worse, as I wasted 25 minutes writing a clear, precise and resource packed answer for the community and I couldn't post it. I was sooooo annoyed, as the notification appeared right at the end of my writing.

My feeling right now is that I cannot be bothered to answer anymore questions on StackOverflow, as I would prefer for this to not happen ever again. But, I'm sure this can be resolved for future contributors. Surely there can be something in place to allow answers to be posted if they clicked 'Answer' before the notification was displayed.

I've just seen this [meta question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276597/better-notification-of-closed-question-in-process-of-being-answered) but users are saying that the current notification is clear enough to warn you. However, I feel this is grossly incorrect and unfair, as the notification could appear 20 minutes after you start answering, like it did to me. Yes, the notification was VERY clear, but it doesn't prevent your time being wasted as a contributor.

Comment: Just open your console and take that disabled attribute out of the button.

Comment: If it is a question that can be closed quickly, it is best not to attempt to answer it. If the question was answerable, edit it to clarify, then it will be reviewed for reopening and you can post your answer.

Comment: @Rizier123 are you saying you can clobber the code to post an answer to a closed question (presumably if you had already started writing it)? Why would that be a good thing to do? I memory serves, the system used to allow you to post if you had already started. Presumably that is no longer desirable.

Comment: Thanks for your comments so far; notes taken. The last two closures were down to duplication. The last one was closed 10 minutes after posting and the one before that was closed 2 hours after - I was just unlucky that somebody found a duplicate answer that was titled completely differently, but content was pretty similar to be fair.

Comment: @BillWoodger There is a server-side grace period for submitting an answer if you started writing it, so you can enable the button back and try it.

Comment: @BillWoodger: unfortunately, the author of the question decided to remove the question. It was here, but removed now: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33695794/mail-php-not-sending-with-godaddy

Comment: @Rizier123 thanks, I can also see reference to that in Tim's answer.

Comment: Thanks. I think I've had questions (here) deleted out from under me. Yes, that would be frustrating, but not sure that there's much that can be done about that. Then the old saw, how to more effectively identify duplicates, so that they don't cause things like this? That is a tricky one. Perhaps you can post your answer (if it adds) on the duplicate-target?

Comment: If you feel the question and answer are worthy, and not a duplicate, you could just rewrite the question yourself and answer it. Obviously it would have to meet the same quality standards as any other Q&A, but it would save your time (at the expense of more of your time :)).

Comment: If the questions were closed as duplicates then look at the canonical posts; if the content of your post is adding value to the answers already there, post your answer there.  If it's not, move on.

Comment: PaparazzoKid, throwing a tantrum isn't going to help you or us. Far better to just accept that some people will disagree with you and move on. First step would be to read and understand the answers.

Comment: @paxdiablo: nobody is throwing a tantrum - I suggest you read it all again and stop being rude and trying to wind me up more. I'm airing my frustration about a subject, also known as feedback. If you have nothing constructive to add to this discussion, why don't you move on.

Comment: @PaparazzoKid You started complaining about downvotes and people disagreeing with you when you proposed making it so that questions that the community has determined shouldn't be answered should allow you to post answers.  I don't know why you're surprised at that result, but even so, complaining because people disagree with you is pretty much throwing a tantrum.  You provided your feedback, the community felt that it doesn't have merit.  Move on.

Comment: @PaparazzoKid, deleting your comment where you stated you were ragequitting SO then claiming that you weren't throwing a tantrum is a very ... revisionist thing to do :-) I'm not trying to wind you up, just explaining the reality of the situation which I believe *is* helpful. Still, I've said my peice, it's totally up to you how you take it. SO is a valuable resource and I'd be sorry to see any contributor leave, especially when there are valid solutions to the original problem.

Comment: But, 'nuff said, I think, further discussion is unlikely to add more. You may have the last word if you wish, I am, as you suggest, moving on, something you may also want to consider. Good luck in future.

Comment: When you write answers to bad questions, you incentivize bad questions and **you contribute to the demise of the site**. Please don't do this.

Comment: @bjb568: 'contribute to the demise of the site' - hahaha, that's a funny one. The question was a very good question but somebody found a duplicate that was titled very differently and it was closed due to that reason, unfortunately as I was writing an answer for 7-8 minutes. A duplicate titled differently isnt necessarily a bad question. I don't answer bad questions and usually vote to close them myself. I also help StackOverlow with reviewing flagged questions, so forgive me for being defensive, but **I am NOT contributing to SO's demise**.

Comment: @TheCarver As the questions is deleted, I can't look at it in detail, but from the link you posted, the title of the question is "mail-php-not-sending-with-godaddy". I'm not exactly imaging a stellar question here, on the contrary, from the data I have gathered it appears the question is a help request (NARQ) that's probably one or more of Too Broad, Unclear, and OffTopic reason 13 in addition to a dup of similar help requests, also mostly off-topic, of similar pseudo-programmers trying to spam users and who are stuck with GoDaddy and a lack of debugging skills.

Comment: @bjb568 - 'As the questions is deleted, I can't look at it in detail' - so why on earth are you judging me and accusing me of 'contributing to the demise of the site' based on questions you cannot see? I think that's silly, especially as the title may have been edited by the author or a moderator after it was posted. My question here was answered 3-months ago - you cannot and, are not, adding anything constructive to this question and discussion. I suggest you dismount your high horse and move along - you've clearly said what you came to say, albeit pretty useless.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's more of a question of *when* your time might seem wasted. Imagine if you did post the answer, and got some up-votes, and the question was deleted a week later? Disabling the button isn't just blocking answers from being posted, it's helping not set your expectations that an answer to a closed question will be around for very long.

That said, I've been bitten by that at least two dozen times, I've never quite been happy with how the current behavior works, especially since it's trivial to simply enable the button again (or just post the form) from a console. Can't guarantee that hack will work forever, though.

So let me ask you this, which is more irritating? Let's say that 70% of everything you answer that was closed is going to be removed (as the questions themselves are deleted by the community). Would you be *more* irritated after expecting some sort of permanence when the answer is accepted?

What I'm getting at is, there's a more than likely chance that an answer posted to a question that was closed shortly after being asked is going to be removed relatively quickly along with the question (well, not totally removed, but not visible to those with less than 10k rep). Letting people post despite knowing that is better? It could be, but I'm not certain.

Comment: [Sometimes the mob gets it wrong, though.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252657/1079354)  I wonder if that'd be something worth testing out in a limited capacity to see if that might be beneficial.

Comment: @Makoto: it is rare enough that the mob gets it wrong. I don't think exceptions should dictate how things work.

Answer (score 6):

One thought that you seem to have not considered yet.

If the actual question was a *useful* one and you disagree with the closure reason (this has happened to me where the OP has seemingly just decided to close for no reason), there's nothing to stop you asking it *again* and self-answering.

That's perfectly acceptable provided you don't run afoul of the other rules (like asking a duplicate or off-topic question).

That way your effort won't be wasted, and your useful content will stay around for others who may have the same issue (as in the deleted question, not *this* question).

Answer (score 6):

Questions are closed because they are unsuitable for the site. Either for being off topic, or because they can not reliably have one correct answer.

Avoiding your "problem" is simple. Don't even try to answer unsuitable questions. Such questions *and their answers* are unwelcome. And if you don't know what kinds of question are suitable, educate yourself.

Comment: It's not always that simple. I agree that you shouldn't try to answer bad questions, but it's happened to me several times that I was writing an answer to a good question which turned out to be a duplicate. The question seemed perfectly OK and I had no way of knowing in advance that it was a duplicate. Often I couldn't even see if there were pending duplicate votes or a "possible duplicate" comment since the question was closed using a dupehammer.

Comment: @Donald Duck Yes you can know it is a duplicate. You can search. If you are looking at a question in a popular  tag, the question probably is a duplicate.

Comment: It's not always easy to find duplicates just by searching. Of course in some cases it is, and in those cases I usually find the duplicate and vote to close myself. But there are cases where the duplicate can be hard to find if you haven't seen it before.

Answer (score 4):

> I left my feedback here and now people are downvoting my feedback - that is kind of pathetic

You seem to misunderstand how voting works on Meta. While the tooltips are the same as on the main site, in reality the voting as more about agree/disagree than useful/not useful. And for better or worse, one of the risks of expressing an opinion in public is that people might disagree with your opinion. And for what it's worth, I do disagree with your opinion. But let me explain why…

First, let me emphasize that I *do* understand your frustration. It is in fact annoying to spend any non-trivial time of anything, only to find that time has been "wasted". But I have found that it helps to look at the question more philosophically: is the time *truly* wasted, if *some* good comes from it?

Maybe homework one stayed up late doing turned out to not be collected by the teacher. Or maybe one lost several hours of progress in a computer game due to a bug. Or maybe one carefully composed a reply to some question, only to find that reply was ignored or could not even be posted. But in each of these cases (and any case like them) there are things to be gained from the experience; the practice alone is helpful and improves one's skills.

One might be able to ask the teacher to grade one's homework anyway, to receive feedback on needed areas of improvement. If you're playing a game that is so bad you really don't want to have to play some section of it again, maybe you picked the wrong game. And I have found that helping answer others' questions is an excellent way for me to expand my knowledge and improve my own skills in an area.

So as a general rule, I think it's helpful emotionally to look at such experiences as opportunities rather than wasted time. One almost never comes away from such experiences having gained nothing, so "don't worry, be happy". :)

Now, all that said, I think it's also useful to consider, if this is really happening to you on anything close to a frequent basis, maybe you should be rethink how you choose the questions you answer. I'm not saying this is your problem for sure, but it's worth considering whether you are succumbing to the temptation to be [The Fastest Gun in the West](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9731/fastest-gun-in-the-west-problem).

I say that, because for those who are following the FGITW strategy, it's quite common to focus on answering as quickly as possible, before stopping to think whether a question *should* be answered.

The most obvious reason a question shouldn't be answered is that **it's already been asked and answered!** While Stack Overflow strives to develop a repository of useful questions and answers, it also strives to present exactly those questions and answers exactly once. It is not useful for there to be a great deal of redundancy, especially in the answers (for questions, leaving them as bread crumbs to find the real answers can be useful).

I think there are a number of good reasons for this, but to me the biggest one is a thorough researcher is going to have to read through every single answer to figure out what information is most relevant to them. If 80% of the content is just a reiteration of the other 20% of the content, they are going to have to spend five times as long figuring out their answer than they otherwise would have.

The easiest questions to answer are also the ones that are the most general and the most likely to already have been asked and answered. If a question seems simple for you to answer, maybe you could do the site a favor and spend some time looking for the duplicate, rather than writing yet another answer to it.

Note that "duplicate" is a stock close reason. Indeed, you can save yourself a lot of trouble by looking at questions skeptically and voting to close instead of answering, if you can. Overly broad questions, unclear questions, opinion-based questions, are all likely to be closed.

And if you are unable to do a better job predicting what questions are likely to be closed, you might want to take a break from answering and spend more of your time refining your understanding and intuition of what gets questions closed.

Finally…if all else fails, type faster. :)

Comment: *"Finally…if all else fails, type faster"* - yeah that's what SO needs, more hit & run answers :)

Answer (score -4):

I wouldn't be surprised to get many downvotes, but I think I have a workaround: next time I'll see a question that I am answering I'll post the answer and then edit it later.

I too think it should be allowed for users to answer questions that got closed while answering.

Comment: Note that if your initial answer is incomplete, it may well get flags in that state, and those will be entirely deserved.

Comment: But it will flustrate me less than my wasted time and hopefully after editing it it'll be upvoted or even accepted

Comment: If it's an answer of at least acceptable quality when you post it, feel free. If it isn't, you are just abusive to anyone wasting his time looking at your construction site and especially those tricked into wasting even more time pointing out to you where your answer fails.