# Earlier warning about closed questions (ajax perhaps)

Tags: feature-request

Today I was working on an answer for this question: [How to add text to JSON with php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47582364/how-to-add-text-to-json-with-php)

The question was gaining upvotes, but nothing else. Once I finished my answer, I posted it. Only to notice that the question was closed almost 20 minutes ago.

Would it be possible to get a warning about questions being closed without refreshing the page first? Like with new comments?

I know it's a minor issue, but it's best practise not to answer closed questions. Considdering the amount of time you sometimes put into an answer, it can be usefull to be notified about it while you have the question open.

PS: I did find this related question here on Meta: [Questions being closed as answers are being written](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/310144/questions-being-closed-as-answers-are-being-written) but it's about being able to answer or not. I don't think this is a duplicate because all I'm asking is for an earlier warning, possibly through Ajax?